# Is there some kind of Facebook like view callback?

Tags: android, facebook, callback

I'm trying to implement facebook like view on Android, but with some call back and notification when user is tapped it. I've tried everything and google it allot and could not find anything useful. When I try to add `View.OnClickListener` to a like view it doesn't trigger. So far I have this code:

```
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
         "https://www.facebook.com/SomePage",
         LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BUTTON);
            likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
likeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TO DO
                }
    });
```

Is this even possible? I just want to know when facebook like view is pressed. Thanks for your answers and help.

Comment: Why do you need to know if they liked?

Comment: I'm handling that currently in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`  and `sendBroadcast(intent)` methods. But what I need is to perform click on parent view when like view is clicked. So this is the reason why I need to detect LikeView tap.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack. It is important to identify inner LikeButton inside LikeView. Than you can handle onTouch event on it. It is enough for me (need to log on button clicked).

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) widgetView.findViewById(R.id.button_fcb);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "<< page id >>",
            LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
    LikeButton likeButton = findLikeButton(likeView);
    if (likeButton != null) {
        likeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ... do anything ...
                return false;
            }
        });
    }    

private LikeButton findLikeButton(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (childView instanceof LikeButton) {
            return (LikeButton)childView;
        }
        if (childView instanceof ViewGroup) {
            return findLikeButton((ViewGroup)childView);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```